# Finding drivers from nearest locations of a given location

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

**Table 1 - drivers**

[image: Table 1 - drivers]

**Table 2 - location**

[image: Table 2 - location]

**Table 3 - distance**

[image]

User will search for a driver that matches a location. In drivers table the location refers to the current location of the driver. If a driver is not available in a particular location, I want a query to search for a driver that is closest to the location that the user has provide.

Table 2 is the location names and Table 3 is the distance from one place to another. But the problem is, if distance from locationid 1 to locationid 2 is stored, opposite version is not (locationid 2 to locationid 1).

Comment: so write that query. Sounds like fun and Joy.

Comment: In practice distance is measured by `time` in Dhaka. (:p) . Please show what you have tried and also share your expected output based on some sample input.

Comment: Hahaha! Yes. That's right. :p

Comment: Couple of things need to be clarified. How do you identify available drivers? And does your expected result set consist of at most one entry? What does the user search with? Does the user search with text like `Mirpur`?

Comment: If you have tried any query, share it. It would be great for others to help you out. Seems like a long story :D

Comment: The user sees the available areas with a Select box where the options are generated from database. The user selects a location. But if a driver is not available on that location, the drivers that are closest needs to be generated.

Comment: What if the user searches with "Gulshan"? What's your expected output for the above input set?

Comment: No driver is at Gulshan now. So, the location that is closest to Gulshan and has available drivers needs to be found. For example, Banani is closest and has drivers, so Drivers in Banani should be the output. Here all the drivers are in Banani, But say if some driver was Mirpur, he wouldn't be in the output as Banani is closer than Mirpur from Gulshan

Comment: How many rows do you want if there are multiple drivers found?

Comment: Multiple drivers can be there. No problem.

Comment: Share the scripts of the table with sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not straight forward.

First you need to get all the location with which the given location has a relationship. This result includes the `locationid` and `distance`.

The distance with the location itself is zero. I've taken help of `UNION ALL` in order to make a list of `<locationid,distance>`.

Then make an `INNER JOIN` between the above list and your `drivers` table on matching `location`.

And finally sort the result set based on `distance` in ascending order.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM drivers DR 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    locationid,
    0 AS distance
    FROM location 
    WHERE locationname = 'Gulshan'

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
    IF(L.locationid = D.fromid, D.toid, D.fromid),
    D.distance
    FROM location L
    INNER JOIN distance D ON L.locationid IN (D.fromid,D.toid)
    WHERE locationname = 'Gulshan'
) AS t
ON DR.location = t.locationid 
ORDER BY t.distance
```

---

[**See Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/RALT39852)

OR

[**See SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e38018/1/0)

---

**Note:** You may include `LIMIT n` in order to restrict the result set containing at most top `n` search results.

You can also include a `..WHERE distance < MAX_ALLOWABLE_DISTANCE...` in your query so that the final result makes some sort of sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer!